# Idempotent WebAPI

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, idempotent

In a game scenario

When a player opens a chest, it receives an item. The item is generated randomly based on a loot table and the probability for each item of being dropped is configurable.

The main requirement is that the web service is idempotent and the loot table to be configurable at runtime.

How can this service be implemented?

My approach was to inject the loot table with the probability for each item into the query string. Also the player ID together with the chest ID can be used as a seed to generate random items.

For example:

http://[URL]/api/OpenChest?loottable=Sword:10|Shield:10|HealthPotion:30&playerId=1&chestId=1

This way the call doesn't have any side effects and the web server can cache the response as it will always return the same item for that player from a particular chest.

Is this correct? is this service idempotent? and is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: If the loot table is injected client side, your players will cheat.

Comment: Consider that the loottable will be encrypted. For simplicity, in this post, I left it decrypted.